# Transforming triple integration into spherical or cylindrical

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am just doing bunch of examples.

https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~emsilvia/math21c/mshwsc11.pdf

For 5 a) and 6 a)

I don't understand why boundary of $\theta$ is $0$ to $2\pi$ and $0$ to $\pi/2$ respectively.

Since our solid is in first octant, shouldn't it be from $0$ to $\pi/2$ ?

Why the boundary of theta for 5 a) is $0$ to $2\pi$?

Comment: Please rewrite the exercises on this site! This question becomes useless if the link dies, and it is hard to search.

Comment: Oh I am sorry, cause I don't know how to write this in fancy and mathematical way.

Comment: [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is some info on how. For example, `$$\iiint_S\sqrt{x^2+y^2}dV$$` becomes $$\iiint_S\sqrt{x^2+y^2}dV$$